# LSTM Model Multivariate input and single output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to understand in depth LSTM. I am trying to predict the power generation of a wind power plant. For this prediction I am using the historical power from the plant and 4 weather variables, The interval from these variables is hours. Is it possible to predict the next 24 hours based on the last 24 hours of data (power and weather variables)?

I understand that there are models of a single input variable (power) where they use the single output variable (power) as a new input but how does it work when you have more than one input variable (weather variables) and you do not have the future values ( t+1, t+2) of these to re-enter them in the algorithm to continue making the power prediction as it was done when there was only one variable (power).

How is it possible to predict several points of a single variable in the future based on variables of which it is known only up to time t?

The LSTM algorithm maintains the relationships of the entered variables and does not need new entries of the climatological variables (t+1, t+2,.. t+n) to be able to predict the electrical power?

```
def df_to_X_y(dataset, window_size=6):
  dataset_as_np = dataset.to_numpy()
  X = []
  y = []
  for i in range(len(dataset_as_np)-window_size):
    row = [r for r in df_as_np[i:i+window_size]]
    X.append(row)
    label = dataset_as_np[i+window_size][0]
    y.append(label)
  return np.array(X), np.array(y)
```

```
X_train, y_train = X[:25000], y[:25000]
X_val, y_val = X[25000:31250], y[15000:31250]
X_test, y_test = X[31250:32500], y[31250:32500]
X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_val.shape, y_val.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape
```

```
#LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer((6, 5)))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(8, 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, 'linear'))

model.summary()
```

```
Model_LSTM = ModelCheckpoint('Model_LSTM/', save_best_only=True)
model.compile(loss=MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(),tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(
    name='root_mean_squared_error', dtype=None
)])
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have to store the information of hidden_states, and then you will use that information for predicting future states,
Try this code, for your future 24 hours predictions...

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(6,5))
x = LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(_input)
x = LSTM(64 , activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(x)
hidden_states = LSTM(5 , activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(x)
dense = Dense(8 , 'relu')(hidden_states[:,-1])
output = Dense(1 , 'linear')(dense)

model = keras.Model(_input , [output , hidden_states])
model.summary()

output , hidden_states = model.predict(np.random.randint(0 , 10 , size = (1 , 6  ,5)))

results = []
for i in range(10):
    output , hidden_states = model.predict(hidden_states)
    results.append(output[0][0])
```